# Regex to allow all characters and special characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to allow all special characters and characters using regex.

Currently I have it set up like this

```js
const textValidation = new RegExp("^[A-Za-z0-9_ -]*$");
```

How would I modfiy this code to allow special characters as well?

Edit:
The special character I want to allow are parentheses, this along with all the other characters

Comment: You can do many things to allow _all_ characters (`"."`, `"^"`, ...). But why do you need an expression that doesn't filter anything?

Comment: Try using `.`, which will match any character. You may want to add the `s`, or dotall option so it will match a newline as well

Comment: use `/[\w\W]*/` matches any character (\w) or non-word character (\W)

Comment: What *kind* of special characters? If you just want to match everything, use `.`, as suggested by others above, or `[^]`.

Comment: If you want to allow all characters and special characters, why do you need a regex then? if you plan to allow all then you don't need a regex check, as everything is allowed. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain it well in the question but basically I need to allow parentheses it should have been phrased that way

Comment: You can add them to the character class `^[A-Za-z0-9_ ()-]*$` or `^[\w ()-]*$` Note that using `*` will also allow empty strings to match.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this.

```
const myString = "This is a string with special characters like & and #.";
const myRegex = /[\w\W]*/;

if (myString.match(myRegex)) {
  console.log("The string matches the regular expression.");
} else {
  console.log("The string does not match the regular expression.");
}
```

The regular expression matches any character (\w) or non-word character (\W) zero or more times. The [] brackets define a character set, and the backslash () is used to escape the W to match non-word characters instead of the word characters matched by \w. The * means to match the character set zero or more times.

Comment: Do you have an example string when this regex will not match?

Comment: No it will always matches. Because the question says, allow all characters. @Thefourthbird